# Can't stage new project in Eclipse git

Tags: java, git, eclipse, egit

I had a project in Eclipse, version controled in a local file system git repository. Because of other problems, I had to re-install Eclipse and took the opportunity to install the latest Eclipse update, Version: 2023-06 (4.28.0). Then, I "re-installed" the project in Eclipse. This project resides in the workspace directory of Eclipse. Before putting this project under git control again, I migrated the project to java modules. Next, I deleted the former project git directory in the git root directory in the file system. The git root directory and the Eclipse workspace directory are on the same level my users home directory.
So in the Eclipse Java view, I right clicked the project and selected Teams -> Share project. In the dialog I created a new git project at the same old git root location, having the same name as the old previous project.

In the Java view the project has now the git master tag.

[image].

When I now go to the Git Staging tab, irrespective of whether I do this in the git- or the Java view, I see as expected all the files of the project in the "Unstaged Changes" window. But clicking the double green plus icon, the single green cross icon, trying to move the files with drag and drop into the Staged Changes window, right click a file and select "Add to index" - nothing moves the files from Unstaged to Stage. Git remains stubborn and the  Commit button disabled.

[image]

On the file system all files were copied to the git project directory. I guess this is the base for the Unstaged file list.

I also don't see any kind of git error message. Is there a log file, and if so where? Maybe there is somewhere a git configuration file that is outdated and mixing up with my old and my new setup?!

The Git setup in Eclipse is:

[image]

Please let me know if you need further information. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It seems the logic of the UI changed from the Eclipse version I was used to?! Whenever I edit a file, it shows up in the lower Staged window. However, ifI  then commit, the Staged window is not cleared, but all the files are still in Staged. I don't get this. Any guidance?

Comment: Is the issue maybe related to the  "Unborn branch: This commit will create the branch master" ? Although the message doesn't disappear after I commit.